# Formulas for partial composed product

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, polynomials, sequences-and-series, recurrences

Let $A(x) = \prod\limits_i (x-\lambda_i)$ and $B(x) = \prod\limits_j (x-\mu_j)$. Then, their composed product is defined as
$$
(A*B)(x) = \prod\limits_{i,j} (x-\lambda_i \mu_j).
$$
Generally, we can show that if $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ have integer coefficients, so does $(A*B)(x)$. The reason for this is that if $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are characteristic polynomials of matrices $A$ and $B$, then $(A*B)(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of $A \otimes B$, their Kronecker product.

Now, let's focus on the composed product of $A(x)$ with itself. We can define polynomials $A_d(x)$ and $A_s(x)$ as

$$\begin{align}
A_s(x) &= \prod\limits_{i < j} (x-\lambda_i \lambda_j), \\
A_d(x) &= \prod\limits_i (x-\lambda_i^2),
\end{align}$$
in which case $(A*A)(x) = A_d(x) A_s^2(x)$. It appears that $A_s(x)$ and $A_d(x)$ should also have integer coefficients if $A(x)$ is as such, but I don't see any simple way to show it, or compute them without finding the roots, like it was possible with $(A*B)(x)$. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Ideally, I want to not only show that $A_s(x)$ and $A_d(x)$ have integer coefficients, but also provide some algorithmic way to find them if $A(x)$ is known, without finding all complex roots of $A(x)$.

The reason I ask is, assume that $A(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of a linear recurrent sequence $u_n$. Then, $A_s(x)$ is the characteristic polynomial of the linear recurrent sequence $h_n = u_n u_{n+a+b} - u_{n+a} u_{n+b}$, and more generally, $A_s(x) A_d(x)$ appears to be the characteristic polynomial of $h_n = u_n u_{n+a}$, so it would be nice to have a general method to find it directly.

Comment: If the degree of $A$ is $n$, then $A_d(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n m_{2^k}(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n) x^{n-k}$, where $m_{2^k}$ is the monomial symmetric function for the partition $(2,\dots,2)$.  The monomial symmetric functions are integer linear combinations of the elementary symmetric functions.  Finally, the elementary symmetric functions are the coefficients of $A$.

Comment: $A_s$ is the characteristic polynomial of the exterior square, and $A_dA_s$ is the characteristic polynomial of the symmetric square. They multiply up to the tensor square, and their quotient is $A_d$.

Comment: While above comments are of course correct, life is much more prosaic: $A_d$ is simply the characteristic polynomial of $A^2$. So, it has integer coefficients. Then, $A_s^2 = (A*A)/A_d$ also has integer coefficients, thus $A_s$ has integer coefficients (by Gauss's lemma, say).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the comments! I will try to summarize what's going on a bit, and post it as an answer, as I was not really aware of how symmetric squares and exterior squares work, so I will provide somewhat more explicit constructions and explanations.

**Tensor product** of vector spaces $U$ and $V$ is the vector space $U \otimes V$ with a bilinear map
$$\begin{gather}
\otimes: U \times V \to U \otimes V, \\
(u, v) \mapsto u \otimes v,
\end{gather}$$
such that $\{u \otimes v : u \in B_U, v \in B_V\}$ is a basis of $U \otimes V$, where $B_U, B_V$ are bases of $U$ and $V$.

Now, let $B_V = \{e_1,\dots,e_n\}$ and we will focus on the vector space $V$.

**Tensor square** $V^{\otimes 2}$ of a vector space $V$ is $V \otimes V$, it has a basis
$$
\{e_i \otimes e_j : 1 \leq i, j \leq n\}.
$$

**Symmetric square** $\operatorname{S}^2(V)$ of a vector space $V$ is the subspace of $V^{\otimes 2}$ with a basis
$$
\{e_i \otimes e_j + e_j \otimes e_i : 1 \leq i \leq j \leq n\}.
$$
**Exterior square** $\bigwedge^2(V)$ of a vector space $V$ is the subspace of $V^{\otimes 2}$ with a basis
$$
\{e_i \otimes e_j - e_j \otimes e_i : 1 \leq i < j \leq n\}.
$$

Generally, tensor square is isomorphic to the linear space of $n \times n$ matrices, while symmetric square and exterior square can be interpreted as subspaces of symmetric and antisymmetric matrices correspondingly.

For any matrix $A$, we can represent it as $A = \frac{A+A^\top}{2}+\frac{A-A^\top}{2}$, the sum of a symmetric and antisymmetric matrices, meaning that $V^{\otimes 2} = \operatorname{S}^2(V) \oplus \bigwedge^2(V)$, i.e. the tensor square is a direct sum of the symmetric square and the exterior square.

Now, if $A : V \to V$ is a linear transform on $V$, we can induce a linear transform
$$\begin{gather}
A^{\otimes 2}:V^{\otimes 2} \to V^{\otimes 2}, \\
u \otimes v \mapsto (Au) \otimes (Av),
\end{gather}$$
which we will call its tensor square. Correspondingly, its symmetric square $\operatorname{S}^2(A)$ and exterior square $\bigwedge^2(A)$ are the reductions of the tensor square on corresponding subspaces. Since the tensor square of a space is the direct sum of the symmetric square and the exterior square, the tensor square of a linear map is the direct product of its symmetric square and exterior square.

Let $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $A$, and $e_1,\dots,e_n$ the eigenvectors. Then,

- The eigenvalues of $A^{\otimes 2}$ are $\lambda_i \lambda_j$ for all $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ and eigenvectors are $$e_{ij} = e_i \otimes e_j$$
- The eigenvalues of $\operatorname{S}^2(A)$ are $\lambda_i \lambda_j$ for $1 \leq i \leq j \leq n$ and eigenvectors are $$e_{ij} = e_i \otimes e_j + e_j \otimes e_i$$
- The eigenvalues of $\bigwedge^2(A)$ are $\lambda_i \lambda_j$ for $1 \leq i < j \leq n$ and eigenvectors are $$e_{ij} = e_i \otimes e_j - e_j \otimes e_i$$
- The eigenvalues of $A^2$ are $\lambda_i^2$ and eigenvectors are $e_i$.

These observations altogether pretty much explain how to represent

- $A_s(x) A_d(x)$ as the characteristic polynomial of $\operatorname{S}^2(A)$,
- $(A*A)(x)$ as the characteristic polynomial of $A^{\otimes 2}$,
- $A_s(x)$ as the characteristic polynomial of $\bigwedge^2(A)$,
- $A_d(x)$ as the characteristic polynomial of $A^2$.